# java - detect action performed on JPanel in JDialog

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, actionlistener

In netbeans I have a JDialog with a JPanel component (called Keypad). I simply draged and droped the JPanel Keypad onto JDialog and netbeans generated the code. On the Keypad I have an Enter button for which I am trying to detect ActionPerformed (button pressed) in the JDialog. Is this possible and how do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add an [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) to your *Enter* button. You need to pass a reference to your JDialog in the JPanel constructor so you can communicate with it. You either need to implement ActionListener or you can use an anonymous class:

```
enterButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        // Do something to your JPanel reference
    } 
});
```

Comment: I am such an idiot. My button was private, I forgot to set it as protected...now I can accesses it and use the ActionListener. Thanks for the example, looking at it helped me figure out my problem.

Comment: @jadrijan: I don't see how making it protected is going to help you. This is not a problem that inheritance will solve. Nor should you make it public. Instead you will want to pass messages from one class to another using basic decent OOP techniques, pure and simple.